# I18n and distance_of_time_in_words_to_now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I'm trying to get the distance_of_time_in_words_to_now work a bit more elegantly with i18n.

The problem is that in English, it's ok to say "less than a minute ago" but in Japanese, "1分以内 前" doesn't work. That "ago" translation shouldn't be there basically, but it should after one minute (without a space between characters).

Right now I'm generating that text with `<%= "#{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(message.created_at)} #{t(:ago, scope: 'datetime.distance_in_words')}" %>` but this is incorrect for different locales, so I am thinking of either writing my own helper method to support this slight i18n issue.

Before I do so, however, I'm wondering if there already is something like this included in Rails 4?

One of the reasons I'm reluctant to write my own is because I'm having problems with time zones and ranges:

```
from_time = Time.zone.now
to_time = t1 + 30
range = t1..t2
range.include? Time.zone.now
```

returns `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:368: warning: Time#succ is obsolete; use time + 1`

So I believe i must be doing this the wrong way.
Anyone know if this is already inbuilt somewhere in Rails 4 or if not, any tips on a good way to deal with the time range?

Comment: Regarding your last point, use [`.cover?`](http://pivotallabs.com/reading-the-ruby-source/).

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my issue with the following code, but I think it would be nice for i18n to support this by default.

```
def i18n_distance_of_time_in_words_to_now_with_ago(from_time, include_seconds_or_options = {}) 
  ago = t(:ago, scope: 'datetime.distance_in_words')
  langs = [:ja]
  if langs.include? I18n.locale 
    if(from_time..from_time+60).cover? Time.zone.now
      distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(from_time, include_seconds_or_options)
    else
      space = false
    end
  else
    space = true
  end
  "#{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(from_time, include_seconds_or_options)}#{space ? ' ' : ''}#{ago}"
end
```